Correct SPI interface timing constraints
I'm struggling setting up timing constraints for an ADC SPI interface.
The design is a simple ADC Master interface working at 25 Mhz, same frequency of the system.
First of all I gated the output SCLK with the CS as I have no other possibility (same frequency).
SCLK <= not CLK when CS_N = '0' else '0';
I would rather prefer to make a clock enable and drive a registered clock, but this implies that the max output freq will be half of what I needed.
begin
    if RESET_N='0' then
        SCLK <= '0';
    elsif(CLK'event and CLK='1') then
        if CS_N='1' then
            SCLK <= '0';
        else
            SCLK <= not CLK;
        end if;
    end if;
end process p_sclk;

In this case I think that the gated clock is correct. But this introduces a delay that shall be taken into account during output/input delay constraints. Isn't it?
By doing this I obtain a SCLK that is inverted to the system clock. This is quite good because the ADC sets the data at his SCLK rising edge (system neg edge) and I register it on the rising edge of the system. So I have half cycle to read the data stable.

My first approach to the timing constraints is the next one
#internally generated clock from 100Mhz input 
create_generated_clock -name {system} -divide_by 4 -source [ get_ports { FPGA_CLK } ] [ get_pins { i_main_clock_gen/s_clk_25mhz_i/Q } ]
#ADC CLK
create_generated_clock -name {serial} -invert -divide_by 1 -source [ get_pins { i_main_clock_gen/s_clk_25mhz_i/Q } ] [ get_ports { ADC_CLK } ]

set_input_delay -clock { serial} -min [expr $PCB_dly_min_SDO + $ADC_Tco_min_SDO - $PCB_dly_max_SCK] [get_ports {ADC_DATA}]

set_input_delay -clock { serial} -max [expr $PCB_dly_max_SDO + $ADC_Tco_max_SDO - $PCB_dly_min_SCK] [get_ports {ADC_DATA}]

set_output_delay -clock { serial } -max [expr $PCB_dly_max_CS + $ADC_Tsu_CS - $PCB_dly_min_SCK] [get_ports {ADC_CS}]

set_output_delay -clock { serial } -min [expr $PCB_dly_min_CS - $ADC_Th_CS - $PCB_dly_max_SCK] [get_ports {ADC_CS}]

The next diagram shows the TCO max and min of the ADC

The problem is that the data is being registered by system clock so I suppose that the constraints should be like: TmaxSETUptime = T/2 -TCO_max - T_delay TminSETUPtime = T/2 -TCO_min - T_delay
Where T/2 is half period, 20 ns TCO_max/min are from the ADC datasheet 10/2,5ns T_delay is the delay introduced from s_clk_25mhz_i/Q pin to ADC_CLK pin.It depends on the place and route
What about Hold times? How can I translate this to set_input_delay? Should I just set the constraint to system instead of serial clock?
What I'm missing? I'm quite confused....
I hope you can clarify me this a little bit
By the way I have tried observablehq.com/@nturley/spi-timing-constraints,  but it does not fit what I need.

Note that the timing constraint language is highly specific to the toolchain you are using, even though the timing parameters themselves are tool-agnostic.

I finally found the correct solution. At least checking the STA results seem to have sense. My first approach was correct, despite the input delay constraints can also be written respect to the system clock adding manually the Serial clock generation Delay. The STA slack result is the same in both cases

A common way to build a gated clock output is to use a DDR output block, and output the enable signal during the high phase of the input clock, and constant '0' during the low phase
That allows you to use the same clock distribution net for all the logic and the output, so you get minimal skew, and doesn't require the toolchain to generate an awkward routing between (high-fanout) clock and (flexible) data routing resources.

Ritcher , thanks but this is not an option for me. I'm using a Microsemi Igloo2 Device that has a DDR controller, but for managing a memory. I don't think that it can be used for this specific topic. What is more, I'm not allowed to use any embedded IP cores, only Fabric.

@Carlos, each IO pin should have an IO buffer attached to it. If you do not use an IO primitive, synthesis generates a simple buffer primitive for you that defaults some of the port assignments for you and makes them inaccessible. By explicitly using a DDR capable buffer primitive (typically named something like ODDR), you get access to the other ports on that buffer. The DDR RAM component is largely unrelated, it just shares the name because DDR RAM also uses both high and low phases of the clock for data transfers.

Hi @Simon Ritcher, I have tested with the DDR primitive (DDR_OUT in my case) and it works. It can be seen on the floorplaner how the ADC_CLK output is drived directly from rowglobal clock and CS as enable. But analyzing the timing it provides similar timing values. And simulating the postlayout files provides even worse results with the DDR than without it! (I would like to show you, but I'm not capable to share images or code on this answer...)
